# Why is git status "nothing to commit..." is slighly different on two machines?

Tags: git

I noticed on my 2 servers, one displays this message as `nothing to commit, working directory clean`, and the other as `nothing to commit (working directory clean)`.  Anyone know why it's different?

Comment: Please run `git --version` on each server and show the results here.

Comment: I forgot that even though both servers are up to date, they are running different OS versions, so the version of git managed by there respective package managers is different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In all likelyhood, they're simply using different versions of Git. I have two systems that have 1.7.2.5 and 1.8.4 installed, and they also differ in the same way within the exact same project (and the exact same working directory, over NFS), with the older version using the parenthesized form.

Comment: Yeah, one is using 1.7.* and the other is using 1.8.*.

Comment: The change was made in commit `50bd8b7eb960ff7a646195e0751b48a0e57e03ad`, 2012-09-06 22:16:50 +0700. I'll let someone else track down which release that first showed up in.